# When I am going through a foreach loop, it changing everything in my list to the new data getting added?

Tags: c#, list, selenium, foreach

I have a method I am using for a test that takes the data in a table row, turns it into a string then uses the `Split()` function to add each different string to an object in my class. I then take that and try and add it to a list of the same class. Each time it runs through the foreach loop it is just updating each object to the new data that is supposed to be added so that the data is the same in each index whereas it is supposed to be different. How can I fix this?

Here is the method:

```
public List<IMUItemModel> tableData()
        {
            _webDriver.Wait.UntilPageLoadIsComplete(60);
            List<IMUItemModel> IMUDataList = new List<IMUItemModel>();
            IMUItemModel IMUData = new IMUItemModel();
            
            foreach (var row in IMUDataTableRows)
            {
                string column = row.Text;
                var split = column.Split(' ');
                IMUData.MedVendID = split[0];
                IMUData.DeviceSerialNumber = split[1];
                IMUData.ItemID = split[2];
                IMUData.Station = split[3];
                IMUData.Console = split[4];
                IMUDataList.Add(IMUData);
                Console.WriteLine(IMUData.MedVendID);

            }
            return IMUDataList;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a single instance of `IMUData` for entire list and so, the same reference is being assigned the values in each iteration. At the end of the iteration, all the items will have the data of last item because you just kept on updating the same reference.

To fix this,

> move the below line inside the `foreach` loop

```
IMUItemModel IMUData = new IMUItemModel();
```

This will ensure you have a new reference each time you add an item to the list.